# how to end-up template layers?

Tags: c++, templates

When having:

```
template <typename Super>
class Whatever : public Super
{
    ...
};
```

is it possible, to create `Whatever` class without deriving from something?

Is this the lighter version?

```
struct BlankType{};

Whatever<BlankType> w;
```

////////////////////////////////////////

Some background:

I have my code composed into template layers like `Whatever` above. So I can do:

```
typedef Whatever<Whenever<Wherever<>>>> MyCombinedType
```

actually I can not. I have to do

```
typedef Whatever<Whenever<Wherever<BlankType>>>> MyCombinedType
```

and the type becomes also BlankType.
I can not make `Wherever` "non-layerable", because when I would do just

```
typedef Whatever<Whenever<>>> MyCombinedType
```

the problem will appear again...

Comment: `is it possible, to create Whatever class without deriving from something?`.. I think you want to ask something ? Because answer for this question is always yes. Just don't derive anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to create `Whatever` class that is not derived from something you can simply define its specification as follows:

```
class BlankType {};
template<typename T = BlankType> class Whatever : public T {};
template<> class Whatever<BlankType> {};
```

Comment: ok, with this, I save some writing, but my type still be derived from BlankType. My question was, if this is the only solution or `is it possible, to create Whatever class without deriving from something?`

Comment: @relaxxx, `Whatever<BlankType>` (and `Whatever<>`) is not derived from `BlankType`, because specialization of `Whatever` class created for `BlankType` differs from the default one. You can read about template specialization [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Comment: thank you, I have misread your example. Now I get it, Whatever<BT> wont be derived from anything, but what about the rest of class Definitions between {}; ? Doesn't I have to duplicate it?

Comment: @relaxxx, yes you have to do it. If it is too annoying, there are several workarounds. For example, you can derive default class from `Whatever<BlankType>`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit off-topic, in C++ with variadic templates you can avoid the recursive instantiation thanks to a recursive definition:

```
template <class ...Bases> class Whatever;

template <class B, class ...Bases>
class Whatever<B, Bases...> : public B, public Whatever<Bases...> { /* ... */ };

template <class B>
class Whatever<B> : public B { /*... */ };

template <> class Whatever<> { /* ... */ };
```

Now you can say `Whatever<Foo, Bar, Baz>` and inherit from all those. If you want to inherit also from multiply nested other instances of `Whatever`, you should make all the inheritances virtual.

The final specialization in my example also shows how you can specialize `Whatever` to not derive from anything. If you write `Whatever<> x;`, you have an object of a class that does not derive from anything.